# Flutter how to do an Avatar Creator?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Is there a way to create an avatar/emoji creator which saves an SVG or the styles in strings? You know, like the one Snapchat has.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/avataar_generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this :

```
dependencies:
  avataar_generator: ^1.1.2

import 'package:avataar_generator/generator.dart';

void main() {
  print(getSvg(new Options()));
}
```